# How can I increase a series by all increments and not a set percentage increase?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to increase a set of numbers by all combinations. I am able to increase the series by a set percentage but not all combinations.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For a = 1 To 10
    For i = 60 To 90
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") * (1 + a / 1000)        
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2") * (1 + i / 1000)            
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3") * (1 + i / 1000)          
    Next i
Next a
```

So for example, I am able to increase one row to the next by 6% and then 7% etc. But what if I want to increase each row by all combinations?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For a = 1 To 10
        Set rng = .Range("B" & a + 1)
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value * (1 + a / 1000)
        Dim c As Integer: c = 2
        For i = 60 To 90
            rng.Offset(0, c).Value = rng.Offset(0, (c - 1)).Value * (1 + i / 1000)
            c = c + 1
        Next i
    Next a
End With
```